# How to display the featured image on a Commerce product:

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

How do I display the featured image on a Commerce product:

```twig
<figure>
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
        <img src="{{ entry.featuredImage[0].getUrl('medium') }}" alt="">
    </a>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach is always to check if the element even has a related asset or not, otherwhise you'll receive exceptions.

```TWIG
{% set asset = entry.featuredImage.one() %}
{% if asset is not null %}
    <figure>
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
            <img src="{{ asset.getUrl('medium') }}" alt="">
        </a>
    </figure>
{% endif %}
```